# Partial derivative with respect to difference of two variables

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

My specific question: Is $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial (x-y)}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$$
valid? If not can $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial (x-y)}$ be expressed as a function of $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When differentiate a multivariable function with respect to a variable, you can make use of the concept of total derivative.

$$\frac{df}{du}= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

So in our case, set $u=x-y$

Then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} =1$

$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=-1$

So indeed, your statement is correct.